# Bounds for the logarithmic derivative in the Selberg Class

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, selberg-class

Let $F \in \mathcal{S}$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the set of $L-$functions in the [Selberg Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class). Are there established upper and lower bounds for $$\left|\frac{F^{'}(s)}{F(s)}\right|,$$ where $s = \sigma + it$? 
Any help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried playing with Jensen's formula and Borel-Caratheodory lemma? These are typically used to establish bounds for logarithmic derivatives of $\zeta(s)$ and $L(s,\chi)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I would try using those two ideas.

Comment: Perhaps [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.10771) could be useful for some cases you're interested in?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, assume that $L(s)$ is entire.  Writing the completed $L$-function for $L(s)$ as
$$
\Lambda(s) = q^{s/2} L(s)\prod_{j=1}^d \Gamma(\lambda_j s + \mu_j),
$$
let's define the analytic conductor of $L(s)$ to be
$$
C = q \prod_{j=1}^d(|\mu_j|+1)^{\lambda_j}.
$$
Using Jensen's formula, we can prove that if
$$
\max_{\substack{k\geq 0, \\ k\in\mathbb{Z}}}\Big|s+\frac{k+\mu_j}{\lambda_j}\Big|\geq \frac{1}{2}
$$
and $\rho$ ranges over the zeros of $\Lambda(s)$, then
$$
\frac{L'}{L}(s) = \sum_{|\rho-s|\leq 1}\frac{1}{s-\rho}+O(\log(C(|s|+3))).
$$
Moreover, we know the number of zeros $\rho$ (counting multiplicity) such that $|\rho-s|\leq 1$ is $O(\log(C(|s|+3)))$.  Without more information on where the zeros are (e.g., a zero-free region) or how close the nearest zero is to $s$, this is essentially the most that one can say.